# Giving null object reference on fileoutputstream.close is called?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fileoutputstream, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to get RGB from Bitmap and save JPEG image at the same time when JPEG byte array is available from `ByteBuffer` in android camera2 api here is my code:

```
private class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
private final Image mImage;
private ImageSaver(Image image) {
    mImage = image;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytes);
    final byte[] myBytes = bytes;
    Thread getRGB = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myBytes, 0, myBytes.length);
            for(int y=0; y<bmp.getHeight();y++) {
                for(int x=0; x<bmp.getWidth();x++) {
                    int c = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
                    pixel++;
                    red += Color.red(c);
                    green += Color.green(c);
                    blue += Color.blue(c);
                }
            }
        }           
    };
    getRGB.start();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFile);
        fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mImage.close();
        if(fileOutputStream!=null)
        {
            try {                       
                fileOutputStream.close();                       
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

here is exceptions now i'm getting

> 03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715): FATAL EXCEPTION: My Camera2 Basic App
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715): Process: com.example.mycamera2basicapp, PID: 19715
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715): java.lang.NullPointerException: file == null
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:84)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at com.example.mycamera2basicapp.MainActivity$ImageSaver.run(MainActivity.java:145)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>   03-13 19:26:26.199: E/AndroidRuntime(19715):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

here where I'm initializing mImageFile:

```
@Override
            public void onCaptureStarted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, long timestamp,
                    long frameNumber) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCaptureStarted(session, request, timestamp, frameNumber);
                createImageGallery();
                try {
                    mImageFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

and createImageFile() is simple function that creates a JPEG file:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "Jpeg_Image_"+timeStamp+"_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", mJpegGalleryFolder);
    mImageFileLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

when i comment the lines

```
    pixel++;
red += Color.red(c);
green += Color.green(c);
blue += Color.blue(c);
```

file gets saved with no error at all.
My intention is to get RGB and save the image at the same time can someone help me regarding this problem or can show me some other direction where I can save image and can utilize RGB too.

Comment: Well, obviously the first catch block was entered, so `fileOutputStream` is null. This is easily solvable with an if null check before you close your resources

Comment: now it is give me this java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest$Builder android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: how have you defined mImageFile ? does calling fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mImageFile); instantiates fileOutputStream?

Comment: Please edit your question with new information rather than the comments. Also that error isn't from the code you've shown in your question. But NullPointerExceptions are easy to fix. Just make sure all the variables on the line of the error can't be null.

Comment: yes I did with created file under [CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html) [onCaptureStarted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html#onCaptureStarted%28android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20long,%20long%29)

Comment: Ok @cricket_007 sorry im new to stackoverflow.

Comment: That's alright. Please find the edit link between the comments here, and your question

Answer (score 0):

Put the calls to `close` in conditionals, e.g.

```
if (fileOutputStream != null) {
  try {
    fileOutputStream.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Assuming you are using Java 7 (or more recent), you should really use try-with-resources instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andy's answer, I like to use this utility class for it:

```
public class CloseUtils {

public static void close(AutoCloseable ...autoCloseables) throws Exception {

    Exception firstException = null;

    for (AutoCloseable autoCloseable : autoCloseables) {

        try {
            if (null != autoCloseable) {
                autoCloseable.close();
            } // if
        } catch (Exception e) {

            if (null == firstException) {
                firstException = e;
            } else {
                firstException.addSuppressed(e);
            } // else
        } // catch
    } // for

    if (null != firstException) {
        throw firstException;
    } // if
} // ()

public static Exception closeQuietly(AutoCloseable ...autoCloseables) {
    try {
        close(autoCloseables);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e;
    } // catch
} // ()


} // class
```